# Entity Framework 4.0 GetChanges() equivalent

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In LINQ to SQL, you can override SubmitChanges and use the method this.GetChangeSet() to get all the inserts, updates and deletes so that you can make last minute changes before it is committed to the database.

Can this be done in EF 4.0?  I see there is a override for SaveChanges but I need to know the equivalent for GetChangeSet()

Answer (score 16):

Found it.

ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added); for inserts.

Comment: Related links I found helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx and http://blog.tonysneed.com/2010/02/19/trackable-dtos-taking-n-tier-a-step-further-with-ef4/